# Как сгенерировать датасет с дополнительными условиями на поля данных?

Tags: python, генерация-случайных-данных

Всем доброго дня! Никак не разберусь с заданием:

Нужно сгенерить пайтоном датасет в котором были бы следующие поля:

| название | содержание |
| --- | --- |
| userid | 100 уникальных айди пользователей |
| payment_amount | сумма платежа (рандомное значение), от 5 до 50 платежей у каждого пользователя |
| payment_date | дата платежа, диапазон дат среди всех пользователей не менее 3-х, но не более 5-ти лет. У каждого пользователя должны быть (не менее 3-х) платежи в разные месяца |

Решение почти готово, только не пойму как выставить условие, что у каждого пользователя должны быть платежи в разные месяца. Через условие, что у каждого id должна быть только уникальная дата платежа?

```
rows=[]
for user_id in range(1,101):
    payments_count = np.random.randint(5,51)
    for _ in range(payments_count):
        row = {'user_id': user_id}
        row['payment_amount'] = np.random.randint(1,99) 
        row['payment_date'] = datetime.date(randint(2017,2021), randint(1,12),randint(1,28))
        if 'payment_date' != row['payment_date']:
            rows.append(row)
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
print(df)
```

Comment: а причем здесь мультииндекс? ну и свои попытки приведите в вопросе.

Comment: @strawdog, да, действительно, дело не в мультииндексе. Решение почти готово, только не пойму как выставить условие, что у каждого пользователя должны быть платежи в разные месяца. Через условие, что у каждого id должны быть только уникальные год и месяц платежа?

Comment: rows=[] <br/> for user_id in range(1,101): <br/>
    payments_count = np.random.randint(5,51)  <br/>
    for _ in range(payments_count):  <br/>
        row = {'user_id': user_id} <br/>
        row['payment_amount'] = np.random.randint(1,99) <br/>
        row['payment_date'] = datetime.date(randint(2017,2021), randint(1,12),randint(1,28)) <br/>
        rows.append(row) <br/>
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)  <br/> print(df)

Comment: или сделать так:  <br/> if 'payment_date' != row['payment_date']: <br/> rows.append(row)

Comment: Код добавляйте прямо в вопрос. В комментариях код читать невозможно.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, вам нужно просто генерить случайно платежи, пока не будет достигнуто условие. Хотя если рандом нормальный, то даже минимальные 5 платежей наверняка окажутся за разные месяцы.

Comment: "Хотя если рандом нормальный, то даже минимальные 5 платежей наверняка окажутся за разные месяцы" - по идее да, но хотелось бы автоматически проверить и исключить неподходящие даты

Comment: @CrazyElf спасибо большое за редактирование поста! Не подскажите, где можно почитать, как это делать самому?

Comment: Почитайте про формат `markdown`, он же и на `GitHub` используется и много где, и вот здесь тоже. Этот формат очень полезно изучить.

Comment: Ну, честно говоря, условия так сформулированы, что их непросто понять. На мой взгляд нужно попробовать просто генерить и потом проверять условие. Скорее всего оно всегда будет выполнено.

Comment: @CrazyElf спасибо! А с помощью такого кода "if 'payment_date' != row['payment_date']:" допустимо проверить выполнение условия?

Comment: Я не понимаю, что вы этим проверяете. Что `row['payment_date']` не равно какой-то строке? Ну оно не равно - там же дата лежит, которую вы строкой выше положили. Дата никогда не будет равна строке.

Comment: @CrazyElf а как сделать так, чтобы записалось только уникальное значение даты, которого ранее не было для конкретного id?

Comment: isin надо использовать, loc и условие написать